# Bluetooth Sending and Receiving Text Data

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm new to Android developing and I would like to make an app that sends and receive text using bluetooth. I got everything regarding the sending text logically working, but when I try to test it in my phone, I can't see the interface.

Here's the `Main Activity` Code

> ```
> import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity; 
> import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar; 
> import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; 
> import android.os.Bundle; 
> import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
> import android.view.Menu; 
> import android.view.MenuItem; 
> import android.view.View; 
> import android.view.ViewGroup;   
> import android.os.Build; 
> import android.app.Activity; 
> import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter; 
> import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice; 
> import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket; 
> import android.content.Intent; 
> import android.os.Bundle; 
> import android.os.Handler; 
> import android.view.View; 
> import android.widget.TextView; 
> import android.widget.EditText; 
> import android.widget.Button; 
> import java.io.IOException; 
> import java.io.InputStream; 
> import java.io.OutputStream; 
> import java.util.Set; import java.util.UUID;
>
>
>
> public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
>
>
> BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
>   BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
>   BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
>
>   OutputStream mmOutputStream;
>   InputStream mmInputStream;
>   Thread workerThread;
>
>   EditText myTextbox;
>   TextView myLabel;
>
>   byte[] readBuffer;
>   int readBufferPosition;
>   int counter;
>   volatile boolean stopWorker;
>
>   @Override
>   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>       try {
>           Button sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
>           Button openButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.open);
>           myTextbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
>           myLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
>
>           openButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>               @Override
>               public void onClick(View v) {
>                   try {
>                       findBT();
>                       openBT();
>                   } catch (IOException ex) {
>                   }
>
>               }
>           });
>           // send data typed by the user to be printed
>           sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>               public void onClick(View v) {
>                   try {
>                       sendData();
>                   } catch (IOException ex) {
>                   }
>               }
>           });
>       } catch (NullPointerException e) {
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       } catch (Exception e) {
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       }
>   }
>
>   // This will find a bluetooth device
>   void findBT() {
>
>       try {
>           mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
>
>           if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
>               myLabel.setText("No bluetooth adapter available");
>           }
>
>           if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
>               Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(
>                       BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
>               startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
>           }
>
>           Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter
>                   .getBondedDevices();
>           if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
>               for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
>
>                   // Salaxy S4 is the name of the bluetooth device
>                   if (device.getName().equals("Galaxy S4")) {
>                       mmDevice = device;
>                       break;
>                   }
>               }
>           }
>           myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Device Found");
>       } catch (NullPointerException e) {
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       } catch (Exception e) {
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       }
>   }
>
>   // Tries to open a connection to the bluetooth device
>   void openBT() throws IOException {
>       try {
>           // Standard SerialPortService ID
>           UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
>           mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
>           mmSocket.connect();
>           mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
>           mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();
>
>           beginListenForData();
>
>           myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Opened");
>       } catch (NullPointerException e) {
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       } catch (Exception e) {
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       }
>   }
>
>   // After opening a connection to bluetooth device,
>   // we have to listen and check if a data were sent to be printed.
>   void beginListenForData() {
>       try {
>           final Handler handler = new Handler();
>
>           // This is the ASCII code for a newline character
>           final byte delimiter = 10;
>
>           stopWorker = false;
>           readBufferPosition = 0;
>           readBuffer = new byte[1024];
>
>           workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
>               public void run() {
>                   while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()
>                           && !stopWorker) {
>
>                       try {
>
>                           int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
>                           if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
>                               byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
>                               mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
>                               for (int i = 0; i < bytesAvailable; i++) {
>                                   byte b = packetBytes[i];
>                                   if (b == delimiter) {
>                                       byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
>                                       System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0,
>                                               encodedBytes, 0,
>                                               encodedBytes.length);
>                                       final String data = new String(
>                                               encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
>                                       readBufferPosition = 0;
>
>                                       handler.post(new Runnable() {
>                                           public void run() {
>                                               myLabel.setText(data);
>                                           }
>                                       });
>                                   } else {
>                                       readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
>                                   }
>                               }
>                           }
>
>                       } catch (IOException ex) {
>                           stopWorker = true;
>                       }
>
>                   }
>               }
>           });
>
>           workerThread.start();
>       } catch (NullPointerException e) {
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       } catch (Exception e) {
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       }
>   }
>
>   /*
>    * This will send data to be printed by the bluetooth
>    */
>   void sendData() throws IOException {
>       try {
>
>           // the text typed by the user
>           String msg = myTextbox.getText().toString();
>           msg += "\n";
>
>           mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
>           // tell the user data were sent
>           myLabel.setText("Data Sent");
>
>       } catch (NullPointerException e) {
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       } catch (Exception e) {
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       }
>
>   }
> }
> ```

and here's my `Fragment_main`

```xml
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.bt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.bt.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Enter Text Here" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/open"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/send"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/send"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:text="Open" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Send" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recievedText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/send"
        android:layout_below="@+id/send"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Received Text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rtArea"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/recievedText"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/recievedText"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Received Text Will be Displayed Here..." />

</RelativeLayout>
```

my `Manifest`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bt"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.bt.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

So I would like to know:

1. Why can't I see the interface and test my code?
2. How can I receive text inside the app itself?

Appreciate all your help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One step at a time.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

will set the content of the view and i am assuming its defined in your Fragment_main should be fragment_main as its a XML file. So if you change it to

```
setContentView(R.layout. fragment_main);
```

you should be able to see the user Interface.

Comment: It works! Thank you, now how would I receive the text that was sent through this app?