# NullPointerException - sending/receiving data through Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, nullpointerexception, android-bluetooth

I would like to send and receive some data through Bluetooth. I followed this post: [Bluetooth Sending and Receiving Text Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23922865/bluetooth-sending-and-receiving-text-data?rq=1)

My **MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.proba2x8;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //@Override
    //protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //}
//}
//public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
  BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
  BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

  OutputStream mmOutputStream;
  InputStream mmInputStream;
  Thread workerThread;

  EditText myTextbox;
  TextView myLabel;

  byte[] readBuffer;
  int readBufferPosition;
  int counter;
  volatile boolean stopWorker;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      try {
          Button sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
          Button openButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.open);
          myTextbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
          myLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

          openButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  try {
                      findBT();
                      openBT();
                  } catch (IOException ex) {
                  }

              }
          });
          // send data typed by the user to be printed
          sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  try {
                      sendData();
                  } catch (IOException ex) {
                  }
              }
          });
      } catch (NullPointerException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

  // This will find a bluetooth device
  void findBT() {

      try {
          mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

          if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
              myLabel.setText("No bluetooth adapter available");
          }

          if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
              Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(
                      BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
              startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
          }

          Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter
                  .getBondedDevices();
          if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
              for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {

                  // Xperia mini pro is the name of the bluetooth device
                  if (device.getName().equals("Xperia mini pro")) {
                      mmDevice = device;
                      break;
                  }
              }
          }
          myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Device Found");
      } catch (NullPointerException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

  // Tries to open a connection to the bluetooth device
  void openBT() throws IOException {
      try {
          // Standard SerialPortService ID
          UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
          mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
          mmSocket.connect();
          mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
          mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();

          beginListenForData();

          myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Opened");
      } catch (NullPointerException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

  // After opening a connection to bluetooth device,
  // we have to listen and check if a data were sent to be printed.
  void beginListenForData() {
      try {
          final Handler handler = new Handler();

          // This is the ASCII code for a newline character
          final byte delimiter = 10;

          stopWorker = false;
          readBufferPosition = 0;
          readBuffer = new byte[1024];

          workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                  while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()
                          && !stopWorker) {

                      try {

                          int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                          if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
                              byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                              mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                              for (int i = 0; i < bytesAvailable; i++) {
                                  byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                  if (b == delimiter) {
                                      byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                      System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0,
                                              encodedBytes, 0,
                                              encodedBytes.length);
                                      final String data = new String(
                                              encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                      readBufferPosition = 0;

                                      handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                          public void run() {
                                              myLabel.setText(data);
                                          }
                                      });
                                  } else {
                                      readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                  }
                              }
                          }

                      } catch (IOException ex) {
                          stopWorker = true;
                      }

                  }
              }
          });

          workerThread.start();
      } catch (NullPointerException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

  /*
   * This will send data to be printed by the bluetooth
   */
  void sendData() throws IOException {
      try {

          // the text typed by the user
          String msg = myTextbox.getText().toString();
          msg += "\n";

          mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
          // tell the user data were sent
          myLabel.setText("Data Sent");

      } catch (NullPointerException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

  }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Text Here" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/open"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/send"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/send"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:text="Open" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/send"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:text="Send" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/recievedText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/send"
    android:layout_below="@+id/send"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Received Text" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rtArea"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/recievedText"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/recievedText"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Received Text Will be Displayed Here..." />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My problem is, that every time I push the send button, the following error(NullPointerException) is shown in the LogCat:

```
11-26 00:11:58.650: W/System.err(2236): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 00:11:58.650: W/System.err(2236):     at com.example.proba2x8.MainActivity.sendData(MainActivity.java:215)
11-26 00:11:58.650: W/System.err(2236):     at com.example.proba2x8.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:75)
11-26 00:11:58.654: W/System.err(2236):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2418)
11-26 00:11:58.654: W/System.err(2236):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4233)
11-26 00:11:58.654: W/System.err(2236):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6645)
11-26 00:11:58.654: W/System.err(2236):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3763)
11-26 00:11:58.654: W/System.err(2236):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:968)
11-26 00:11:58.654: W/System.err(2236):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:968)
11-26 00:11:58.654: W/System.err(2236):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:968)
11-26 00:11:58.654: W/System.err(2236):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
11-26 00:11:58.654: W/System.err(2236):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
11-26 00:11:58.654: W/System.err(2236):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2064)
11-26 00:11:58.654: W/System.err(2236):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
11-26 00:11:58.654: W/System.err(2236):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
11-26 00:11:58.654: W/System.err(2236):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-26 00:11:58.654: W/System.err(2236):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-26 00:11:58.654: W/System.err(2236):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4370)
11-26 00:11:58.654: W/System.err(2236):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 00:11:58.654: W/System.err(2236):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-26 00:11:58.654: W/System.err(2236):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-26 00:11:58.654: W/System.err(2236):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-26 00:11:58.654: W/System.err(2236):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

For better understanding row 215 is:

```
mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
```

I don't know if it is important or not, but the row 75 is the following:

```
sendData();
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: `mmOutputStream` is null. Maybe it's already closed?

Comment: How can I get to know if mmOutputStream is closed or not?

Comment: More likely it is not open yet, as you have not pushed the open button before the send button (or it has failed).  Your code appears to have catch blocks which are silent, hiding errors from you.

Comment: At first I pushed the Open button, and just after this pushed the Send button.